# java help on hover for a custom framework method

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a custom framework jar and I need to add proper detailed help.

When I use an interface reference, when I hover I get the below help which is confusing.

```
String method1(String arg[0], String arg[1]))
```

When I directly reference its implementation, mouse hover shows correct help.

```
String method1(String transid, String action)
```

Also how do I add custom detailed help for my methods in the custom jar.

I use eclipse as my ide.

Comment: Have you tried [documenting the method](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html) using comments?

Comment: Will comment s show up on hover? I didnt see any of those details.

Comment: @Sibish so long as they are Javadoc comments (double star instead of single star multi-line comments), they will appear on class, method and field in most IDEs

Comment: /**
  ** info(transactionId, app_name, event_name, action, desc, result, reason, additln_fields)
  ** transactionId = Unique Id
  **/

Comment: i tried putting comment in this way, still it doesnt show up